# Do we need the [crapware] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/196558/uninstalling-ie9) question brought to my attention the [`[crapware]`](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/crapware) tag, in this context being used to refer to IE9.

In fact there are 6 tagged questions this way, so it's hardly a widespread issue, but it's better to bring these things up sooner than later, right? Anyway, in the other cases it seems to be used to refer to pre-installed software, which I think is the "correct" usage of the term.

I personally think the term "crapware" is itself a little argumentative/subjective, especially if people start using it to refer to IE, for example.

Basically, I'm calling a close vote on a tag; what does everyone else think?
Kill the tag? Replace the tag? Update just this question? Do nothing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some searching I have merged it with bloatware. I have also made bloat a synonym to bloatware to make it simpler in future.

Comment: If you wanted, there's also the equally apt, [preinstalled-software] for a few that aren't just rants.

Answer (score 7):

I'd vote to kill the tag - but I think we might need to come up with a tag that describes the stuff that gets loaded onto PCs (particularly laptops) by the big manufacturers.

We could then make `[crapware]` a synonym for that so it won't get created again.

Comment: I agree that we can get rid of it if a suitable synonym could be found.

Comment: This is my preferred option - get rid of the tag, but preferably replace it with something meaningful at the same time.

Comment: I agree. Let me know what the valid synonym is and I will merge it.

Comment: How about [Shovelware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shovelware)?

Answer (score 0):

I say leave it, it seems to low volume to be a problem.

I created it's wiki so hopefully it easier to see it's proper use.

Comment: Low volume does not constitute keeping a tag. Personally I prefer the site to pass most corporate spam and profanity filters if at all possible.

Comment: @Diago - A noble goal, but it's not going to help in this case unless you also replace crapware with bloatware in the questions. And like it or not, crapware is almost 3 times as common as bloatware (1.08M vs 400k hits on google)

Comment: On Super User bloatware was more common. So I merged it. We have bigger concerns then what is the most common on Google, and I am more concerned with users being able to access the site and not getting blocked by corporate firewalls. The tag is as far as I am concerned a meta tag anyway. You'll learn that all goals on SE is noble.

Answer (score 0):

from the description you have gave I feel like Bloatware is a less harsh term to use to describe software that is installed that you don't necessarily need as part of another software install most paid antivirus software is full of Bloatware such as tune-ups and email scanners. so I would change the tag to "Bloatware" and change the description